# Undefined push when trying to insert to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new to Javascript, I wanted to push all the data inside my text file to array, it works fine I do this:-

```
var pokemon_array = [];
$.get('pokemonlist.txt', function(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            var arr = lines[i].split('"');

            pokemon_array.push(arr[1]);
            pokemon_array.push(arr[3]);
            pokemon_array.push(arr[4]);
        }
        console.log(pokemon_array);
    });
```

I wanted it to have 2 dimensional array so I put this:-

```
var pokemon_array = [];
$.get('pokemonlist.txt', function(data) {
        var lines = data.split('\n');

        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            var arr = lines[i].split('"');

            pokemon_id = arr[1];
            pokemon_img = arr[3];
            pokemon_name = arr[4];

            pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_id);
            pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_img);
            pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_name);
        }
        console.log(pokemon_array);
    });
```

Then I received this error:-

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

Anything I did wrong here?

Comment: `pokemon_array[i]` is not an array, you'll need to define it as such first `pokemon_array[i] = []; pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_id); .....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `pokemon_array[i]`, which would be `pokemon_array[0]`, `pokemon_array[1]` etc. was never assigned.

You can change the code to something like:

```
        pokemon_array[i] = [];
        pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_id);
        pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_img);
        pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_name);
```

Or

```
pokemon_array[i] = [pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name];
```

Or you can just write it shorter because you can just use the array you have:

```
pokemon_array[i] = arr;
```

But you don't need the `[i]` at all really, so you can go like:

```
pokemon_array.push([pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name]);
```

which can be even shorter as mentioned above:

```
pokemon_array.push(arr);
```

This does not just append each element in `arr`. It adds the entire `arr` as one element of `pokemon_array`, as you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination!

Comment: No problem. Please see the updated answer about multi-dimensional array in particular. And kindly accept the answer if it solves what you want, or leave another comment telling me what problem you still have. Cheers :)

Comment: I got a question, is it possible to add a new value on based on the key?
Example:- Instead of `array([0]=>abc,[1]=>def);` I want to make it based on my `pokemon_id` variable, so the output will be something like this `array(['pikachu']=>abc, ['donkey']=>def)` I can't declare the `pokemon_array` inside the function else it will only be usable inside the function, therefore I declaring the variable outside of the function

Comment: If the IDs are unique, you are better off with an object instead of an array. `var pokemons = {};` and `pokemons[pokemon_id] = {id: pokemon_id, img: pokemon_img, name: pokemon_name};`.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_id);
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_img);
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_name);
```

to

```
pokemon_array.push([ pokemon_id, pokemon_img, pokemon_name ]);
```

otherwise `pokemon_array[i]` is not there yet.

Also you'd better either declare your `pokemon_...` variables with `var` or just do `pokemon_array.push([ arr[1], arr[3], arr[4] ]);` if the only use for them is to be added to array.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because pokemon_array[i] is undefined

```
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_id);
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_img);
pokemon_array[i].push(pokemon_name);
```

to

```
pokemon_array.push(pokemon_id);
pokemon_array.push(pokemon_img);
pokemon_array.push(pokemon_name);
```